# Android EditText title (header) like in android guidelines

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I would like to make every EditText object have own title like in Pure Android guidelines ([screenshot](http://cl.ly/122i293L1b3O090R1f1q))

Is there native support for this thing? I suppose they might also use listview with sections but this seems strange for native applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native support but we have couple of solution.
1) Create a layout file as you required a textview above edittext,etc and every time just include this layout in your XML file.

a layout can be include in other layout by using the below syntax::

```
<include layout = "@layout/dependent_care" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/include_dependent_care"/>
```

2)  As Josephus Villarey Suggested, extend EditText and give it that functionality as you want..

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no native support for such. Although it would be pretty easy to extend EditText and give it that functionality, you can always use a TextView above the EditText.